# how do i communicate 2 bots in webot using emitter and reciever i need creative idea to implement a specified motion

Tags: c, bots, communication, robots.txt, webots

basically i would have 2 mobile bots at the starting of a  path lets imgine the path shape as T and at the long end of T and both bot starts from rest and the bot in front reaches the left or right at T when that happens the bot at back should stop there and wait for the bot in front and the bot in the front goes one path and if the one path is a dead the bot in front should sent comms like its dead and go other way  am trynna do i set up 2 bots and emitter and reciever i dont know hwo to proceed with this motion anyone help

i tried to do it iam not getting any ideas i become dumb anyone one with good ideas or previous knowdledge help

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.